# Multiple argument type in single function

Tags: go

I am using below code and i want single function to take the different struct as argument and return the type and use that struct attributes from calling function. If we use switch inside "FuncPassStruct" then it works but when we return from function "findClassObj", it gives compilation error as "**tmp.Name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)**". How to achieve this ? Any pointer will be good.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type MyClassFirst struct {
    Name string
}

type MyClassSecond struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    cls := MyClassFirst{Name: "Peter"}
    FuncPassStruct(cls)
}

func findClassObj(class interface{}) interface{} {

    switch v := class.(type) {
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T", v)
    case MyClassFirst:
        fmt.Printf("My first class....")
    case MyClassSecond:
        fmt.Printf("My second class....")
    }

    classStr := class.(MyClassFirst)
    return classStr
}

func FuncPassStruct(class interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("class = ", reflect.TypeOf(class))

    switch v := class.(type) {
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T", v)
    case MyClassFirst:
        fmt.Printf("My first class....")
    case MyClassSecond:
        fmt.Printf("My second class....")
    }

    classStr := class.(MyClassFirst)
    fmt.Println("Name is: -----> ", classStr.Name) ------> Working and print peter

    tmp := findClassObj(class)
    fmt.Println("From function: ------->", tmp.Name) ---> Giving compilation error
}
```

Comment: `findClassObj` returns an `interface{}`. An `interface{}` is not a struct so has no fields, and as the empty interface, it has no methods. Start [here in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14) for the relevant tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface with a method to get the name and implement that interface from the two classes. Its much cleaner as below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyClass interface {
   GetName() string
}

type MyClassFirst struct {
    Name string
}

func (m MyClassFirst)GetName()string{
   return m.Name
}

type MyClassSecond struct {
    Name string
}

func (m MyClassSecond)GetName()string{
   return m.Name
}

func FuncPassStruct(class MyClass) {
    fmt.Println("class = ", reflect.TypeOf(class))
    fmt.Println("Name is: -----> ", class.GetName())
}

func main() {
    cls := MyClassFirst{Name: "Peter"}
    FuncPassStruct(cls)
}
```

result:

```
class =  main.MyClassFirst
Name is: ----->  Peter
```

Answer (score -2):

You trying to cast `classStr := class.(MyClassFirst)` but your class can be `MyClassFirst`, or `MyClassSecond` compiler cannot cast it right